# How does the 'Region Hunted Out' status work?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I recently got a 'Region Hunted Out' status after some time hunting animals to grind XP and salvage:

[image]

How does this work?

- Can this status 'reset'? Will the animals 'repopulate' a  'hunted out' region? If yes, what causes, or how long  before a region's animals repopulate a region?
- How many animals can I kill before I get the 'Region Hunted Out' status or: What exactly causes it? Does each region have a different amount of animals I can kill before I get the 'Region Hunted Out' status?
- Does 'region' mean per fast travel camp area, or does 'region' have another meaning?

Comment: I'm revisiting the regions where I didn't get all the stuff so far, and hunted out regions do return to normal. Still don't know what triggers that though.

Comment: Animals will repopulate even after the region is hunted out but killing them awards only 1XP and no salvage. Once in a new region I got this message after killing 1 rat. Either there is XP cap in each region that can be obtained by hunting or each region has cap on experience level of the player, but the limitation is clearly there to prevent players to over-level current content. I don't think you can reset it, you can perhaps return to the region you were before and by completing some of the story might increase this cap, but it is not reset.

Answer (score 1):

From what I observed, this status resets when the region changes somehow. Like when the plane crashes. Before that event, I hunted out this region. I came back several times, even waited a long time, finishing side quests and stuff, but the status never changed. And then the plane crashes and I can hunt normaly there again. Same thing happened on the beach near the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard they reset, but in my first playthrough, this is the second time I hunted out the first coastal forest region. I then read about it and they never returned. I finished the game and I only killed one chicken, after that the Mountain Village region instantly became hunted out also and never returned to normal.