# How can I make animals spawn in Tomb Raider (2013)?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

Back in the earliest stages of the game, I spent a while hunting deer in Coastal Forest, until I was told the region was "hunted out". Then I progressed the story.

Now, I'm somewhat further in the game—I'm currently at 39% completion, about to head from Mountain Village to the Solarii base to rescue Sam. But I can't find any animals anywhere.

I thought the "hunted out" status was only for that one region, and would reset after a while. But now in both Coastal Forest and Mountain Village there are no deer, boars, chickens, or anything else. Is this a bug? Is there a way I can get the animals to start spawning again? I enjoyed the hunting part of the game and it would be nice to be able to do it again (and to get some more xp before the next mission).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the 'Region Hunted Out' status work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108277/how-does-the-region-hunted-out-status-work)

Comment: @galacticninja Unfortunately not; this seems to be something different, since it applies to the whole game rather than a single area. I think I've found the cause and I'm going to try to verify it now.